# SEO friendly URLs being appended?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've built the following htaccess file from googling around and looking at different examples.

My file now consists of the following rules:

```
## Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

## Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

## Rewrite URL to exclude wwww.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

## Actual URL re-writes
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/? profile.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*)/? profile.php?pid=$1&view=$2 [QSA,L]
```

From what I understand, this will rewrite URL's such as http://www.domain.com to http://domain.com, disable listing of directory files (+FollowSymLinks), as well as append a forward slash to urls such as http://domain.com/test and change it to http://domain.com/test/ so there's only one representation of that URL in search engines. Awesome! But, my URL keeps appending the part of the url to be re-written when I click on a link in one of my HTML breadcrumbs...

Example: `http:/domain.com/profile/1/shouts/pictures/all/all/all/all/all/` if I continuously click on the same link... Why is this happening?
This is issue is driving me absolutely insane!

I've tried reading mod rewrite cheatsheets and tutorials, but none of them seem to make any sense to me :(

Edit:

I should note that I'm echoing my a href code with (relative?) links. Is this the correct way of doing things?

```
<a href="<?php echo "profile/". $p_id."/all" ?>">All</a>
```

Edit 2:

I just tried using absolute links too, but getting the same issue. My PHP now reads:

```
<a href="<?php echo $websiteUrl. "profile/". $p_id."/all" ?>">
```

Where `$websiteUrl` = `http://domain.com/` Any ideas anyone?

Comment: No, you should use absolute urls  if you don't want to go into deeper levels from where you are currently at. A relative url is always relative from the url you are at.

Comment: Jut tried changing the links to absolute links, can you check my edit? The strange thing is that even after changing my links to be absolute paths, my URL tooltip on the bottom left of my browser reads http://domain.com/profile/1//all. Why are there 2 slashes here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right but some minor corrections are still needed. Pls try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Rewrite URL to exclude wwww.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## Add trailing slash to url
RewriteRule (?!^.*/$)^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

## Your URL re-writes
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?pid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?pid=$1&view=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.